# Within child and parent processes, variables has same addresses but have different value?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) {
        //adding one to X when it is child process
        x++;
    }
    printf("current X: %d, address of X: %p, process : %d\n", x, &x, pid);
}
```

the result is:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpNFh.png)

So I am new to the Unix and not really familiar with the fork(). If the child process will make a copy of the parent process so that it will have different address spaces. Then, why X on both processes here have the same address but different value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how fork works. It makes a copy of the address-space, actually it makes some optimizations (only changed pages have to be written).

The copy uses the same addresses:

- this is *possible* because the parent and child process will each only see their version
- and it is *required*: if you have any linked datastructure, the pointers from one object to another have to remain valid. If the copied address space would occupy different addresses then all pointers would have to be fixed - and the operating system does not even know which of the bytes are pointers and which are just data.

Comment: Thank you so much! Although, I don't 100% understand how "page" works but at least got an direction what should I look into now :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) on Fork:

> The fork operation creates a separate address space for the child. **The child process has an exact copy of all the memory segments of the parent process.** In modern UNIX variants that follow the virtual memory model from SunOS-4.0, copy-on-write semantics are implemented and the physical memory need not be actually copied. **Instead, virtual memory pages in both processes may refer to the same pages of physical memory until one of them writes to such a page: then it is copied.** This optimization is important in the common case where fork is used in conjunction with exec to execute a new program: typically, the child process performs only a small set of actions before it ceases execution of its program in favour of the program to be started, and it requires very few, if any, of its parent's data structures.